# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32'). Pythorch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, pytorch

I try to train model but in vain. I see the error

```
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

I think it can be connected with Mse function, because with MAE it works somehow also with RMSE it works somehow (on the second epoch i have RMSE = 10). I can't figure out what i do wrong.

[image]

```
# Count Nan
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt.zip', header=None)
X = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = df.iloc[:, 0].values

train_size = 463715
X_train = X[:train_size, :]
y_train = y[:train_size]
X_test = X[train_size:, :]
y_test = y[train_size:]

#ToTensor
X_train = torch.FloatTensor(X_train)
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(y_train)
X_test = torch.FloatTensor(X_test)
y_test = torch.FloatTensor(y_test)

# Create TensorDataset
train_ds = TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
test_ds = TensorDataset(X_test, y_test)

val_num = 92743
train_num = 370972

# Divide train data into train and validation data
train_ds, val_ds = random_split(train_ds, [train_num, val_num])

# Evaluate accuracy
def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
  return r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

# create Class 
class BaselineModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
    super(BaselineModel, self).__init__()
    self.input_size = input_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(90, 45)
    self.linear2 = nn.Linear(45, 1)
    self.linear3 = nn.Linear(45, 15)
    self.linear4 = nn.Linear(15, 1)
    self.batch = nn.BatchNorm2d(hidden_size)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.lreku = nn.LeakyReLU()
    self.elu = nn.ELU()
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
  
  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.elu(self.linear1(x))
    return self.linear2(x)
  
  def training_step(self, criterion, batch):
    x_train, y_train = batch
    y_pred = self(x_train)
    loss = (criterion(y_pred, y_train.unsqueeze(1)))
    return loss
  
  def validation_step(self, criterion, batch):
    x_val, y_val = batch
    y_pred = self(x_val)
    loss = (criterion(y_pred, y_val.unsqueeze(1)))
    acc = accuracy(y_val, y_pred)
    return {'val_loss': loss, 'val_acc': acc}
  
  def validation_epoch_end(self, y_pred):
    batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in y_pred]
    epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()

    batch_accs = [x['val_acc'] for x in y_pred]
    epoch_acc = np.mean(batch_accs)
    #epoch_acc = torch.stack(batch_accs).mean()

    return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc.item()}
  
  def epoch_end(self, epoch, result):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch}, val_loss: {result['val_loss']}, val_acc: {result['val_acc']} ")

model = BaselineModel(input_size = 90, hidden_size = 45, output_size = 1)

# Evaluate 
def evaluate(model, criterion, val_loader):
  with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred = [model.validation_step(criterion, batch) for batch in val_loader]
    return model.validation_epoch_end(y_pred)

# Train 
def train(model, criterion, optimizer, train_loader, val_loader, lr, epochs):
  history = []

  for epoch in range(epochs):
    
    for batch in train_loader:
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      loss = model.training_step(criterion, batch)
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()
    
    result = evaluate(model, criterion, val_loader)
    model.epoch_end(epoch, result)
    history.append(result)
  #return history

# Create train_loader & val_loader
batch_size = 128

train_loader = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = True)

# Create parameters and Train
lr = 0.05
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr, momentum = 0.9)
criterion = F.mse_loss
epochs = 10

train(model, criterion, optimizer, train_loader, val_loader, lr, epochs)
```

[image]

Comment: Replace NaN Values with Zeros in Pandas DataFrame.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-nan-values-with-zeros-in-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because of your loss of function. if the value of the loss function after some epoch becomes very small or very large then when you want to use it in backpropagation to train the model, you face this error. To handle that, you should use **Early Stopping** to Halt the Training. so you should implement **Callback**, Callbacks provide a way to execute code and interact with the training model process automatically.

Comment: Thanks, sir! But I could train my model with MSE earlier with this data, then I started improving my model and it was broke down. Could you give an example with Early Stopping?